# Spark Structured Streaming doesn't work after making a connection with socket

Tags: sockets, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I want to send streaming data from a socket using python to Spark Structured Streaming locally. When I tried this with Netcat It worked. but It doesn't work when I make a Server Socket instead of Netcat.

## Basic Info

- I am working on mac os.
- spark version is 3.1.2
- I coded in two different jupyter notebook pages in the same machine.
  (1) Server Socket (2) Spark Structured Steaming
- I made a server socket with python.

## Here is what I did and response.

- Turned a server socket on.
- Launched Spark Structured Streaming 
  **-> Connection is established in this stage.**
- Send a text to Spark Structured Streaming.
  **-> There is not any response on the cmd.**
- Turned the server socket off
  **-> Spark Structured Streaming shows me the result of what I sent from the Server Socket.**

## Code

### Server Socket

```
import socket
server = socket.socket()
host = '0.0.0.0'
port = 9999
server.bind((host, port))
server.listen(2)
client_socket, addr = server.accept()
print("connection established.")

# Sending data
client_socket.sendall("Text".encode())
```

### Spark Structured Streaming

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.functions import split

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Create DataFrame representing the stream of input lines from connection to localhost:9999
lines = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("socket") \
    .option("host", "0.0.0.0") \
    .option("port", 9999) \
    .load()

# Split the lines into words
words = lines.select(
   explode(
       split(lines.value, " ")
   ).alias("word")
)

# Generate running word count
wordCounts = words.groupBy("word").count()

 # Start running the query that prints the running counts to the console
query = wordCounts \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("complete") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 2):

It should've added "\n" at the end of the line when the Server sends data.

I found a reason at a link down below.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58455506/15002153